Question about the "VolZScore" in this article about applying the Boids algorith to equities to find flocking behavior
In this article, "Flocking behavior of US equities":
https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~lorenzo/teaching/cs174/Archive/Winter2013/Projects/FinalReportWriteup/ira.r.jenkins.gr/final.html
They use a metric, "VolZScore". They conclude regarding this metric:

The current volume and volume three minutes ago are important
Many of the genetic individuals predicted a movement when the trading
volume three minutes in the past was low, but current volume was high.
This indicates that volume has recently increased when previously it
was low. Something was up with that stock!

However, I don't quite understand what this metric actually is. They say:

Our approach is to first calculate a Z-score for each minute of
trading. This is calculated by first determining the average number of
shares traded per minute of each trading day (this varies considerably
during the day, where right after the market open and right before the
market close average share volume is typically much higher than during
the middle of the day) and the standard deviation of the number of
shares at each minute. Then for each sample, we take the current
shares trades and subtract the average shares traded for that minute.
We divide this by the standard deviation of the number of shares
traded.
VolZScore = (v - μ)/σ
Where:
v = volume for this minute of the trading day
μ = average volume for this stock for this minute of the trading day
σ = standard deviation for this stock for this minute of the trading
day.
In this way we normalize a score for all stocks, whether they trade
relatively high volumes or whether they trade relatively low volumes.

And:

NOTE: we normalized these scores by this formula:
VolZScore = (v - μ)/σ
Where:
v = volume for this minute of the trading day
μ = average volume for this stock for this minute of the trading day
σ = standard deviation for this stock for this minute of the trading
day

I'm not sure what this means. Is this using data only for the current day? Or is this using historical averages?
For μ, the term "average" is confusing me. Is this an average volume over many days for that stock? Since if it was just one minute, there would be no average, just a single volume number.
And if so, σ is hen the standard deviation in the average volume for a stock, in a specific minute of the day? I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly.
If anyone understands what exactly this VolZScore means, please educate me.

Volume differs for different stocks and in addition has strong "seasonality" in the sense that volume is high in the early part of the day, is low around lunchtime and picks up again in the last minutes of the day. So if ACME stock trades 1000 shares in the minute from 12:00 to 12:01 today is that a lot or a little? We would compare it to the average volume  for this stock between 12:00 and 12:01 over a historical period: $\mu$. In calculating $\mu$ we would observe that the ACME vol from 12:00-12:01 is not the same for each historical day, but has a std dev $\sigma$ which we can also compute.

If VolZScore is >= 2 we can conclude that today's figure of 1000 shares for ACME from 12:00 to 12:01 was unusually high and if <= -2 that it is unusually low. HTH.
